# Visual Studio 2013 - cannot edit files with my keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-2013, editor

I'm not using Resharper.

New install (Professional 2013) and new user to Visual Studio.

I check out a file and then double click on it to edit it.  The editor brings up the file.  I can cut and paste into the file but I'm unable to edit the file using the keyboard (and the cursor keys don't work inside the file).    If I 'Open With' Notepad I can make changes.

The only modification I've made to Visual Studio is to add the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2013 add on.

Comment: _I check out a file and then double click on it to edit it._ What happens in files you create? Same issue or is this specific to checked out files? If so, what type of repository are you using?